# I can't connect my SMTP server for phpmailer

Tags: php, email, smtp

I want to send an email through the website I created but i can't connect with SMTP server with any port. **I use windows 8.1, does it matter?** If yes, please tell me how to setting SMTP server.

This is my code :

```
IF(isset($_POST['reply_button']))
{
    $tmpEmail=$_POST['email'];
    $tmpName=$_POST['name'];
    $tmpContent=$_POST['content'];

    $message = file_get_contents('mailTamplate/replyMessage.html');

    $message = str_replace('%name%', $tmpName, $message);
    $message = str_replace('%content%', $tmpContent, $message);

    require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->Username = "example@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "password"; 
    $mail->AddAddress($tmpEmail); 
    $mail->FromName = "Example"; 

    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('./images/logo.jpg', 'my-image', 'attachment', 'base64', 'image/jpeg');
    $mail->Subject = $tmpName;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->From = $mail->Username;
    if(!$mail->Send())
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    else
    {
        echo "Message has been sent";
    }
 }
```

Comment: The SMTP server is running under Windows or on a separate box?

Comment: @Machavity: it's the gmail server. there is no local one.

Comment: check for firewalls. My home ISP firewalls the SMTP port for all IPs except their own server as an anti-spam measure. This block makes it literally impossible for any customer's PC to send email via open relays as the relays are totally unreachable.

Comment: I think if this is "$mail->Username = "example@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "password"; "  what you are using in your original code SMTP authorization won't let you mail. Try using an active username and password in place of this dummy data

Comment: also what does this prints btw "echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;" ?

Comment: After instantiateing PHPMailer class, you should 'tell' that mailer should use SMTP, not at the very end of your code. `$mail = new PHPMailer; $mail->isSMTP();` [See simple example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)